# Trouble baking normals to face

Tags: uv, normals

I'm having a little trouble with a normal bake on a face. I unwrapped the low poly head and baked a normal onto the texture from a high poly version. The normal texture looks good but I'm getting a big color difference on the model where my uv seam is. Happens in Cycles and Eevee. Anyone know of a cause for this? I've been playing with setting forever and can't seem to get it to work.

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should set the normal map image node Color Space to "Non Color". I'm not sure this will fix your shading, but it's the correct to set up a normal map.

Comment: Thanks Paul! That fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Your low poly and hi poly meshes are overlapping. You forgot to turn off rendering for the low poly model. Click the filter icon in the upper right of the Collections panel and choose the camera (and while you're there, the monitor icon). Deactivate the camera for that object.